# The interoperability between redis-graph and redis-streams

Tags: redis, redisgraph, redis-streams

I'm interested in the project and wanna understand more about the internals of RedisGraph, and looks for the feasibility of the interoperability between Redis-Streams and Redis-Graph modules.

Thus, I'm wondering on what native data structures of Redis you have built your own data structure of the 'graphdata' that is shown up when we run TYPE myGraph command.

- Is the graph inside the RedisGraph module (or its sub-components, nodes, edges, paths), is built on the known data structures of Redis, e.g SETS, LISTS,...etc.
- or RedisGraph is using a native new data structure inside its module.
  Thanks in advance for your answer, and support!

Comment: Can you please extend about, what you mean by streams and Graph?

Comment: I mean is there a way to interact with the RedisGraph data structure through Redis-Streams. or in other say, can I stream the graph in Redisgraph using Redis-stream module

Comment: Do you mean you want to capture stream events and update the graph according?

Comment: You might want to check the Redis module https://redisgears.io it allows you to register for stream events

Comment: I want to query the graph in a real-time way, just imagine like in Kafka, the data is coming in a flow, when it comes updates the graph and then we can have a real-time answer for the graph query

Comment: So RedisGears stream processing can give you this Kafka like stream processing to Graph

Answer (score 1):

RedisGraph is using a new data type, it uses sparse adjacency matrices to represent graphs.

You can read more about the internal design here: https://oss.redislabs.com/redisgraph/design/